# Jekyll - Change menu when on posts pages

Tags: jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to build a static website and the front page scrolls to anchor points up and down the page but if the user go off to a post then the menu obviously doesn't go anywhere due the links being like:

```
<li class="nav-link"><a data-scroll-goto="4" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
```

In Jekyll is there a way say in the cofig file to say if post page then replace menu-A with menu-B?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what layouts are made for.

Your `/index.html` page will use the `home.html` template

Your `posts` will use the `post.html` then the `default.html` template

**index.html**

```
---
layout: home
...
---
your content here
```

**_layouts/home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {% include head.html %}
  <body>
    {% include menu-a.html %} <----------LOADING Menu a
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="wrapper">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>
    {% include footer.html %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**_layouts/default.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {% include head.html %}
  <body>
    {% include menu-b.html %} <----------LOADING Menu b
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="wrapper">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>
    {% include footer.html %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah! [facepalm], yes! so simple that worked. Thank you.